# Rotating Function C++

Tags: c++, rotation

**Im trying to rotate a set of values of template class** 
these are the instructions

> Implement a function to rotate values forward among 3 variables. Rotations greater than 3 wrap around. This function must support multiple types and uses the following prototype:
>
> ```
> template <class T>    
> void rotate (T & a, T & b, T & c, int r);
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using std::string; 
using std::endl; 
using std::cin;
using std::cout; 

template <class T> 
void rotate (T & a, T & b, T & c); 

int main () 
{
    int x = 1; 
    int y = 2; 
    int z = 3;  

    cout << rotate(x, y, z) << endl;

    return 0;   
}

template <class T>
void rotate (T&a, T&b, T&c)
{
    T & d = b; 
    while (a != d) 
    {
        swap(&a++, &d++); 
        if (d == c) 
            d = b; 
        else if (a == b) 
            b == d;  

    }
}
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, because it is packed with obvious silly mistakes. You should rectify this. Also, you've either been guessing, or you've misunderstood the `&` operator, because I'm pretty certain that `&a++` will not do what you want it to do, even if that bit of code did compile. Which it doesn't.

Comment: Yes i have been guessing and nothing is working. Can you please correct my mistake. Im trying to make the the numbers rotate.

Answer (score 0):

If I guessd right what you want is the values to rotate among a, b, c. In your original funcion you have int r but in your final implementation r is missing. First of all take the r%3 and rotate by that amount. The rotate is pretty simple you had the initial idea just need to flesh it out properly.

Comment: yes I was stuck on what we were suppose to do with that "int r"   so how would i implement the r .. do i need to make a for loop

Comment: The solution below looks like it will work but  you don't need to run the loop till r just till r mod 3. If you are not allowed to use a loop then just handle the two cases when r is 1 and when r is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your best best would be to use a for loop like this:

```
template <class T>
void rotate(T &a, T &b, T&c, int r)
{
 T temp = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
 {
   temp = c;
   c = b;
   b = a;
   a = temp;
 }
}
```

Then the call in the main function would be:

```
rotate(x, y, z, 4); //4 is the number of rotations
```